# How to create and access a CMS page in Magento as /media

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have a cms page having the url key as media-best.
The client needs to change the url key from media-best to media.
So the new url of the page would be mysite.com/media
But as Magento have a media folder in root, any call would go to the media folder instead of the cms page.
So if I create a cms page as media and access it from url like mysite.com/media  it will show a blank page, since the call go to the media folder.
How this can be done without affecting the media/images and all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ans

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the media folder and add the path as an argument in the shops `index.php` like this:

```
//custom directory location of media
$customDirectories = array(
    'media_dir' => '\media_folder'
);

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType, $customDirectories);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this will not load the images of the product and category which are already there in the media folder. I have checked this in my local and I found that after making the change, the product images are gone. :-(